# Call toString() Child method from parent

Tags: java, inheritance, overriding, multiple-inheritance

I know I can call child method from parent instance, but I need to call `toString()` child from parent instance, I just can't figure out how to determine this.

e.g :

```
class Animal {

// Some code

}
```

---

```
class Chicken extend Animal{

String toString(){

return "I'm a Chicken";
}
}
```

---

```
class Duck extend Animal{

String toString(){

return "I'm a Duck";
}
}
```

I know that I can call child like `Animal cat = new Cat()`

But My issue is that my initiate depend on another initiate e.g:

```
class Farm{

    private Animal animal;

    public Farm(Animal animal){
    this.animal = animal;
    }
    }
```

---

So when I need to call *ChickenFarm()* which is subclass from *Farm.class* I need to get methods from `Chicken.claas` Instead of *Animal.class`.

Is there some way I've missed?

---

Update:

I don't need to make a lot of choices to the client, what I mean that There is a lot of `*Farm.class` classes.

So the client will Only call `Farm.class` with `enum` type or something, how I can determine which child to use by depend on the type Or something e.g (`Type.Chicken`) will go to the team [`ChickenFarm.class` and `Chicken.class`].

Comment: You haven't shown `ChickenFarm` at all, but presumably the `ChickenFarm` constructor should only take a `Chicken`, not any `Animal`. Perhaps you should actually make `Farm` generic instead, so you'd have a `Farm<Chicken>`?

Comment: @Kartik that is useless. If you call toString() on an Animal, and this Animal is a Cat, then Cat's toString() method will be invoked. That's what polymorphism is all about.

Comment: @JonSkeet Please check Update, I added more points to be more clear, I hope that clear now.

Comment: @Smutje fully true, but All sub types of `Animal.class` is under inherit from the main `Animal` and All sub types of `Farms.class` is under inherit from the main `Farm`.

At the end the client will call only the Fram constructor with determining the type, e.g `Farm farm = new Farm(Type.Chicken)` Is there is a way to do that instead of calling subclass e.g `Farm farm = new ChickenFarm()` ?

Comment: @user1058652 yes, please lookup the "factory" design pattern.

Comment: It's still all pretty unclear at the moment. It would *really* help if you'd provide a [mcve]. (Your current code wouldn't compile, and you haven't shown ChickenFarm at all. You haven't shown any methods that are only in `Chicken`, either.) Without a clearer problem description, we're unlikely to be able to help you.

Comment: @Smutje Thanks I think that's what I'm searching for. Thanks :)

Comment: @Smutje after giving a try it didn't cover my need, unfortunately.

Comment: Related to your last edit: Look for "factory" and "enum".

Comment: It's no use to call something like `Farm farm = FarmFactory.create(Chicken.class)`?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to define an interface **IAnimal** with the methods the animals should implement.

Then:

***class Animal implements IAnimal***

and

***class Farm implements IAnimal***

then all subclasses of Animal and Farm (and also ChickenFarm) must implements the aninmals methods.

Comment: I don't think both Animal and Farm should implement the IAnimal class. Poor approach.

Comment: Ok, bui if you change Farm in AnimalFarm it is ok. And the ChickenFarm is a subclass of AnimalFarm!!